# How to delete workbook from tableau server in python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have to upload a lot of worksheets to tableau server.
Many of those will be created and uploaded temporarily. I want to delete some workbook uploaded to tableau server since those are no more in use.
How can I do that in python programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `TSC(Tableau Server Client)`.

```
https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/docs/docs/api-ref.md
```

You can get detailed info there. You can delete the workbook by it's id.

```
workbooks.delete(workbook_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using standard libraries and [tabcmd](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm).

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['tabcmd','login','-s','<server>','-u','<username>','-p','<password>'])
subprocess.call(['tabcmd','delete','<workbookname>'])
```

See documentation for [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more options, including how to get info on failures and output.

Comment: Hi, how would look like a syntax if I would like to download a file as --fullpdf from Tableau server?